# Fatal error: Uncaught AssertionError: assert($mapping instanceof ManyToManyOwningSideMapping)

Tags: symfony, composer-php, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to deploy a Symfony project, but I get an error from GitLab CI/CD while clearing cache with Composer:

```
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
!!  
!!  Fatal error: Uncaught AssertionError: assert($mapping instanceof ManyToManyOwningSideMapping) in [path_to_build]/vendor/doctrine/orm/src/Mapping/AssociationMapping.php:125
!!  Stack trace:
!!  #0 [path_to_build]/vendor/doctrine/orm/src/Mapping/AssociationMapping.php(125): assert(false, 'assert($mapping...')
!!  #1 [path_to_build]/vendor/doctrine/orm/src/Mapping/ClassMetadata.php(1403): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\AssociationMapping::fromMappingArray(Array)
!!  #2 [path_to_build]/vendor/doctrine/orm/src/Mapping/ClassMetadata.php(1980): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata->_validateAndCompleteAssociationMapping(Array)
!!  #3 [path_to_build]/vendor/doctrine/orm/src/Mapping/Driver/AttributeDriver.php(458): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata->mapManyToMany(Array)
!!  #4 [path_to_build]/vendor/doctrine/persistence/src/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/MappingDriverChain.php(77): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AttributeDriver->loadMetadataForClass('App\\Entity\\Arti...', Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata))
!!  #5 [path_to_build]/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Mapping/MappingDriver.php(42): Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain->loadMetadataForClass('App\\Entity\\Arti...', Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata))
!!  #6 [path_to_build]/vendor/doctrine/orm/src/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php(163): Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Mapping\MappingDriver->loadMetadataForClass('App\\Entity\\Arti...', Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata))
!!  #7 [path_to_build]/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php(18): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->doLoadMetadata(Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata), NULL, false, Array)
!!  #8 [path_to_build]/vendor/doctrine/persistence/src/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(343): Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->doLoadMetadata(Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata), NULL, false, Array)
!!  #9 [path_to_build]/vendor/doctrine/persistence/src/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(207): Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata('App\\Entity\\Arti...')
!!  #10 [path_to_build]/vendor/doctrine/persistence/src/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(96): Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor('App\\Entity\\Arti...')
!!  #11 [path_to_build]/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/CacheWarmer/DoctrineMetadataCacheWarmer.php(48): Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getAllMetadata()
!!  #12 [path_to_build]/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/CacheWarmer/AbstractPhpFileCacheWarmer.php(43): Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\CacheWarmer\DoctrineMetadataCacheWarmer->doWarmUp('/home/xemaro/bu...', Object(Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\ArrayAdapter), '/home/xemaro/bu...')
!!  #13 [path_to_build]/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/CacheWarmer/CacheWarmerAggregate.php(99): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\CacheWarmer\AbstractPhpFileCacheWarmer->warmUp('/home/xemaro/bu...', '/home/xemaro/bu...')
!!  #14 [path_to_build]/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(527): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\CacheWarmer\CacheWarmerAggregate->warmUp('/home/xemaro/bu...', '/home/xemaro/bu...')
!!  #15 [path_to_build]/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(725): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer()
!!  #16 [path_to_build]/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(123): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->preBoot()
!!  #17 [path_to_build]/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php(179): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()
!!  #18 [path_to_build]/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php(71): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->registerCommands()
!!  #19 [path_to_build]/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(169): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
!!  #20 [path_to_build]/vendor/symfony/runtime/Runner/Symfony/ConsoleApplicationRunner.php(49): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
!!  #21 [path_to_build]/vendor/autoload_runtime.php(29): Symfony\Component\Runtime\Runner\Symfony\ConsoleApplicationRunner->run()
!!  #22 [path_to_build]/bin/console(11): require_once('/home/xemaro/bu...')
!!  #23 {main}
!!    thrown in [path_to_build]/vendor/doctrine/orm/src/Mapping/AssociationMapping.php on line 125
!!  
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-install-cmd
Running after_script
dircolors: no SHELL environment variable, and no shell type option given
Uploading artifacts for failed job
dircolors: no SHELL environment variable, and no shell type option given
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Here's my files:

`composer.json`

```json
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.11",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.3",
        "doctrine/orm": "^3.1",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "^3.5",
        "jwilsson/spotify-web-api-php": "^6.0",
        "symfony/console": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^2.4",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^2.1",
        "symfony/yaml": "7.0.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.5",
        "psalm/plugin-phpunit": "^0.19",
        "psalm/plugin-symfony": "^5.1",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.56",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "7.0.*",
        "vimeo/psalm": "^5.23"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "php-http/discovery": true,
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php80": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php81": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php82": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php83": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "7.0.*"
        }
    }
}
```

`.gitlab-ci.yml`

```yaml
default:
    image: php:8.3
stages:
    - deploy

deploy-prod:
    stage: deploy
    environment:
        name: production
    only:
        - dev
    before_script:
        - git submodule update --init --recursive
        - export APP_ENV=prod APP_DEBUG=0 YARN_ENABLE_IMMUTABLE_INSTALLS=false DATABASE_URL=$DATABASE_URL
        - composer2 install --no-dev --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader # My web host gives composer for v1 and composer2 for v2
        - php bin/console assets:install --symlink public
        - yarn config set enableStrictSsl true
        - yarn install
        - yarn encore production
        - php bin/console cache:clear
        - rm -Rf $HOME/$PRODUCTION_PATH/node_modules/
        - rm -Rf $HOME/$PRODUCTION_PATH/var/
        - rm -Rf $HOME/$PRODUCTION_PATH/vendor/
    script:
        - php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
        - rm -Rf .yarn/
        - rm -Rf assets/
        - rm -Rf bin/
        - rm -Rf migrations/
        - rm -Rf tests/
        - rm -Rf .env.test
        - rm -Rf .gitattributes
        - rm -Rf .gitmodules
        - rm -Rf .phpunit.result.cache
        - rm -Rf .yarnrc.yml
        - rm -Rf composer.json
        - rm -Rf composer.lock
        - rm -Rf package.json
        - rm -Rf package-lock.json
        - rm -Rf phpunit.xml.dist
        - rm -Rf psalm.xml
        - rm -Rf README.md
        - rm -Rf symfony.lock
        - rm -Rf webpack.config.js
        - rm -Rf yarn.lock
        - cd ../
        - rsync -auO $REPO_NAME/ $HOME/$PRODUCTION_PATH/ --include=public/dist --include=public/.htaccess --include=vendor --exclude-from=$REPO_NAME/.gitignore --exclude=".*"
```

Is there anything I can do to clear this error?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? What makes you think this problem is related to Composer after all?